# Graphql and Typeorm: "No repository was found

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm

Hello for some reason my typel graphl is not working:

[image]

You are creating my database normally, but I cannot insert or select data:

[image]

this is my code

my ormconfig.json:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "spirit",
  "password": "api",
  "database": "emasa_ci",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

my app.ts:

```
export async function startServer() {
  const app = express();
  const schema = await createSchema();
  const connection = await createConnection();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({ req, res }),
  });
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  return app;
}
```

my entity:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column('text')
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @Column('text')
  name: string;

  @Column('text')
  password: string;
}
```

i use ts node for run on dev:

> "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --exec ts-node",

my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the ormconfig.json you are reffering to "entities": `["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"]`.

However, the files are propably not there (or outdated) because you compile with ts-node. 
You should either compile with `tsc` and run the code with `node dist/app.js` or just change the entities path to `["src/entity/**/*.ts"]`.

Ideally you could set up a combination of both. Ts-node is great for development because its compiling in the memory (jit). However tsc will be faster in production because it compiles the whole code into js files (aot).